# After Windows 10 Creators Update, Chrome toolbar is either too small or too big

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, dpi, windows-10-v1703

When I run Chrome with the following arguments I get Chrome toolbar/menus too small:

> /high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1

Without such arguments, toolbar is too big and icons on bookmarks bar get distorted.

Compatibility options have no effect.

My notebook features a FullHD 1920 x 1080 resolution.

Any way to fix it?

Comment: with [v1703, MS made DPI improvements](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/04/04/high-dpi-scaling-improvements-desktop-applications-windows-10-creators-update/) so maybe this effects Chrome

Comment: I think so @magicandre1981, but I have not found any solutions yet ... Anyone?

Comment: [disable DPI scaling](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2900023/some-desktop-applications-may-appear-blurred-on-high-dpi-displays) for chrome.exe